# SPFx, provisioning the DisplayName

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, spfx-webparts, provisioning

I'm trying to provision a sitecolumn in Office365. I'm using the following syntax:

```
<Field ID="{40f80a77-d528-45ae-aafe-e7b15ffa8e6a}"
        Name="LF_Company"
        DisplayName="Company"
        Type="Text"
        Required="TRUE"
        Group="LF Columns" />
```

But for some reason the DisplayName is not provisioned. As far as I can see I'm using the correct syntax.

Any tips on how to set the displayname during provisioning of a list?

Thanks!
Ernst

Comment: BTW: the Microsoft example (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package) does not work as well. (even though they show an image with the correct names...) :(

Comment: can you post your entire elements.xml ? I can try it at my end. The above link works correctly

Comment: You are checking it on the Site Columns right ? There is a chance that your custom list schema has different DisplayName for that column compare to the element of the Column. Also you should try upgrading elements or remove and re-add the app so that the elements will take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `DisplayName="Company "` because Display name "Company" is default site column.

Comment: Thanks, but duplicate DisplayName's are allowed in SharePoint. Also, all other provisioned fields also ignore the DisplayName attribute.